# SQL Server Distinct on ID

Tags: sql-server, date, count, distinct

I'm encountering a problem, when trying to get the right result.
Working on a SQL server.

I want to know how many 'products' of a certain type of material have been made on each day for a period of 6 months.

The problem I'm encountering is the fact that the same product_id can be stored multiple times in the table. However I want those to count as 1. Also I have no clue how to show the count and the date together for multiple days. I've been looking around but I can't seem to find the right page, if there is one, a link to that page is greatly appreciated.

The columns I'm working with are

```
| Product_id | Creation_date | Material |
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) AS total products, 
    creation_date
FROM 
    DB
WHERE 
    MATERIAL = 'dummy'
    AND CREATION_DATE BETWEEN '2022-02-02 00:01:23.763' AND '2022-02-02 23:55:23.763'
```

This is the result I want:

| Total products | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| the count | 2022-02-01 |
| the count | 2022-02-02 |
| the count | 2022-02-03 |

for a period of 6 months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add proper sample data and desired results as text.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY`. If `creation_date` has a time component then you need `GROUP BY CAST(creation_date AS date)`. Please supply sample data and expected output

Comment: "DB" is a very odd table name.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) as total products
, creation_date 
FROM DB 
WHERE MATERIAL = 'dummy' AND CREATION_DATE BETWEEN /startdate/ AND 
/enddate/
group by creation_date
```

If this doesn't help, please provide some sample data and expected output